# Search Form Ability To Ignore Blank Fields

Tags: php, mysql, forms, search

I have made a HTML search form which creates a query to a MySql database based on the contents of a form. What I would love to do is ignore the search parameter if the user leaves that specific form field empty. There are lots of answers online, especially on this website, but I can't get any of them to work.

I have stripped down my code as much as possible to paste into here:

The HTML input:

```
<form action="deletesearchresults.php" method="GET">
  <p><b>First Part Of Postcode</b>
  <input type="text" name="searchpostcode"></b>  </p>
  <p><b>Category</b>
    <input type="text" name="searchfaroukcat"></b>


    <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </p>
</form>
```

The PHP results display:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("myip", "my_username", "my_password") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());


    mysql_select_db("my_db") or die(mysql_error());



   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 
GoogleBusinessData
INNER JOIN TblPostcodeInfo ON GoogleBusinessData.BusPostalCode = TblPostcodeInfo.PostcodeFull WHERE PostcodeFirstPart = '$_GET[searchpostcode]' and FaroukCat = '$_GET[searchfaroukcat]' LIMIT 0,20");


   while($ser = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

      echo "<p>" . $ser['BusName'] . "</p>";
      echo "<p>" . $ser['PostcodePostalTown'] . "</p>";
      echo "<p>" . $ser['PostcodeArea'] . "</p>";
      echo "<p>" . $ser['FaroukCat'] . "</p>";
      echo "<p> --- </p>";

}

?>
```

This works great until I leave one field blank, in which case it returns no results as it thinks I am asking for results where that field is empty or null, which I don't wat. I want all of the results where that form field is empty.

I tried combining a like % [myfeild] % etc but I only want the results to display exactly what is on the field and not just the ones that contain what is in the field, for example searching for the postcode "TR1" would return results for TR1, TR10, TR11 etc.

I believe I may need an array but after 3 days of trying, I just don't know how to get this done.

Any help would be amazing.

edit: Also, I will be adding up to ten fields to this form eventually and not just the two in this example so please bear this in mind with any suggestions you may have.

Comment: stop using the mysql_ function! it is unsafe, you are very very vulnerable to sql injection with this script and it is depreciated!

Comment: @LiamSorsby I am literally just following this [guide](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) to try and transfer a MS Sql database into a useable dashboard that a few people can use online. I am slowly getting there but my php knowledge is very basic.

Comment: you'll need to edit that as you haven't posted the link

Answer (score 0):

try using `isset()`

example

```
if(isset($_GET[searchpostcode]) && isset($_GET[searchfaroukcat])){
 $fields = "WHERE PostcodeFirstPart = '$_GET[searchpostcode]' and FaroukCat = '$_GET[searchfaroukcat]'";
}elseif(isset($_GET[searchpostcode]) && !isset($_GET[searchfaroukcat])){
 $fields = "WHERE PostcodeFirstPart = '$_GET[searchpostcode]'";
}elseif(!isset($_GET[searchpostcode]) && isset($_GET[searchfaroukcat])){
 $fields = "WHERE FaroukCat = '$_GET[searchfaroukcat]'";
}else{
 $fields = "";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM 
GoogleBusinessData $fields
INNER JOIN TblPostcodeInfo ON GoogleBusinessData.BusPostalCode = TblPostcodeInfo.PostcodeFull  LIMIT 0,20";
```

You do however need to escape your $_GET variables however i would highly recommend using PDO/mysqli prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

or try a foreach loop

```
foreach($_GET as $keys=>$value){
$values .= $keys."='".$value."' and"; 
}
$values = rtrim($values, " and");

if(trim($values) != "" || trim($values) != NULL){
$query = "WHERE ".$values;
}else{
$values = "";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `test`".$values;
```

Comment: Yes I was trying to play with a similar bit of code before to get this working but as there will be more fields than in my example, I think the amount of code needed would be huge.

Comment: well you do need to change away from mysql_ as you will find using \ or " or ' will break your code unless escaped and if you upgrade your version of php you may find it won't work anymore

Comment: i've added a different way of going about it. (not tested it though)

Comment: It is giving me : unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING. Dreamweaver is not liking the $values .= $keys"='".$value."' and"; line

Comment: change $keys" to $keys."

Comment: line 29 error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource. Line 29 is my while($ser = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { line. should that still be there?

Comment: no you need to add a line under the $sql with $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error); and then change mysql_fetch_array($sql); to mysql_fetch_array($result);

Comment: I just can't get it to work. I keep getting MySql Error. my full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/Zc5Hf43r) excluding the connection ip's etc. Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: instead of using foreach($_GET as) use $array= array("tblname" => $_GET['value'],"tblname" => $_GET['value']) ect as i beleive the $_GET name isn't going to be the same as your table name. also what are your get variables?